# Can we vote to remove a moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderation

If there is disagreement about a moderator's actions, can we hold a vote to remove them?

Comment: When the permanent mod elections come up (after launch), everyone can leave comments on nominations explaining why they think that candidate should/should not be elected.  This is when the community can vote to elect moderators. You should e-mail team@stackexchange.com if you have serious issues about a moderator.

Comment: meta is for specific issues about the site, not for voting about the moderators. If you want to discuss a specific moderator action, open a new question, if you have a problem with a moderator, write a mail to the SE team.

Comment: If you are going to completely rewrite my question then delete it and post your own please

Comment: your question in its original form was not appropriate.  I had 2 options:  edit the question into something acceptable, or close it.

Comment: Hey, there are elections going on now.  Vote!

Answer (score 10):

A little bit about the current moderators:  the current moderators are [Pro Tempore Moderators](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).  These moderators volunteer their time during the public beta of new sites.  After a site graduates, moderator elections will be held where the community will be able to vote and elect their own moderators.

---

If you have an issue, with a diamond moderator, please use the `contact us` link at the bottom of the page.